# Add two images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to overlay an activation map over a baseline vasculature image but I keep getting the same error below:

> X and Y must have the same size and class or Y must be a scalar double.

I resized each to 400x400 so I thought it would work but no dice. Is there something I am missing? It is fairly straight forward for a GUI I am working on. Any help would be appreciated.

```
a=imread ('Vasculature.tif');
b = imresize (a, [400,400]);
c=imread ('activation.tif');
d= imresize (c, [400,400]);
e=imadd (b,d);
```

Could it be the bit depth or dpi?

Comment: Have you already tried looking at `whos b` and `whos d` to make sure they are what you expect?

Comment: I am guessing one image is RGB and the other is grayscale.  Can you post the output of `whos a b c d`?

Comment: **This question is out-dated**. We can just type `e=b+d` if `b` and `d` are the same type of one of them is a double. This now also does implicit singleton expansion, so that the RGB and the grey-value images do match up and no error would be generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of your images is RGB (`size(...,3)==3`) and the other is grayscale (`size(...,3)==1`).  Say the vasculature image `a` is grayscale and the activation image `c` is RGB. To convert `a` to RGB to match `c`, use `ind2rgb`, then add.

```
aRGB = ind2rgb(a,gray(256)); % assuming uint8
```

Alternatively, you could do `aRGB = repmat(a,[1 1 3]);`.

Or to put the activation image into grayscale:

```
cGray = rgb2gray(c);
```

---

Also, according to the documentation for `imadd` the two images must be:

> nonsparse numeric arrays with the same size and class

To get the `uint8` and `uint16` images to match use the `im2uint8` or `im2uint16` functions to convert.  Alternatively, just rescale and cast (e.g. `b_uint8 = uint8(double(b)*255/65535);`).

Note that in some versions of MATLAB there is a bug with displaying 16-bit images. The fix depends on whether the image is RGB or gray scale, and the platform (Windows vs. Linux).  If you run into problems displaying 16-bit images, use `imshow`, which has the fix, or use the following code for integer data type images following `image` or `imagesc`:

```
function fixint16disp(img)

if any(strcmp(class(img),{'int16','uint16'}))
    if size(img,3)==1,
        colormap(gray(65535)); end
    if ispc,
        set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer'); end
end
```

Comment: You are right- one is RGB and one gray scale. So if I wanted everything in gray scale- which I do- couldnt i just do something like 

    c=imread ('activation.tif');
    d= imresize (c, [400,400]);
    e= rgb2gray (d);
    f=imadd (b,e); 
    figure, imshow (f)

I still get the same error

Comment: Please show the output of `whos b e` with that code, right before `imadd`.

Comment: a=imread ('Vasculature.tif');
b = imresize (a, [400,400]);
e= rgb2gray (d);

Comment: @MostanyLab Yes, that _looks_ right, but please show the output of `whos b e` before `imadd`.  The **class** of `b` and `e` must _also_ be the same for `imadd`. Thanks.

Comment: @MostanyLab Yes, that is exactly right (see my last comment).  Since `b` is `uint16` you need to convert to match `e`.

Comment: Ahhhh- they are not 

 b         400x400            320000  uint16   
 e         400x400            160000  uint8

Comment: @MostanyLab See `im2uint8` and `im2uint16`.  Pick one and convert to match.

Answer (score 1):

*chappjc's answers is just fine, I want to add a more general answer to the question how to solve the error message*

> X and Y must have the same size and class or Y must be a scalar double

**General solving strategy**

1. At which line does the error occur
2. Try to understand the error message

   a. *"... must have the same size ..."*:

   - Check the sizes of the input.
   - Try to understand the meaning of your code for the given (type of) input parameters. Is the error message reasonable?
   - What do you want to achieve?
   - *Useful command*: `size A`: returns the size of A

   b. *"... must have the same class ..."*:

   - Check the data types of the input arguments.
   - Which common data type is reasonable?
   - Convert it to the chosen data type.
   - *Usefull command:* `whos A`: returns all the meta information of A, i.e. size, data type, ...
3. Implement the solution: your favorite search engine and the matlab documentation are your best friend.
4. Be happy: you solved your problem and learned something new.

Answer (score -1):

> A simple code :

```
        a=imread ('image1.jpg');
        b=imresize (a, [400,400]);
        subplot(3,1,1), imshow(b), title('image 1');

        c=imread ('image2.jpg');
        d= imresize (c, [400,400]);
        subplot(3,1,2), imshow(d), title('image 2');

        [x1, y1] = size(b) %height and wedth of 1st image
        [x2, y2] = size(d) %height and wedth of 2nd image

        for i = 1: x1
           for j = 1: y1    
                 im3(i, j)= b(i, j)+d(i, j);
           end
        end

        subplot(3,1,3), imshow (im3), title('Resultant Image');
```

Comment: In MATLAB you can just type `im3=b+d`. Looping is discouraged because it’s a lot slower. Also, if you do loop, you should pre-allocate the output, so it doesn’t get resized every loop iterstion.